# How to root a Huawei GL07S phone?

Tags: rooting, huawei

The [STREAM X GL07S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_STREAM_X_GL07S) is a mobile phone manufactured by Huawei.
It is similar (but different) to the Huawei Ascend P2.

**QUESTION:** How to root the Huawei STREAM X GL07S?

[image: Huawei GL07S]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find a Linux or Windows computer
2. Download and unzip http://gl07s.nakayuki.net/public/emobile-gl07s-root.zip
3. Install the Android SDK tools, in particular the commands `adb` and `fastboot` should be available (fastboot for Windows is provided in the ZIP).
4. Connect your GLS07S via a USB cable
5. Run `sudo ./root.sh` on Linux, or `root.bat` on Windows
6. Three lines of text in Japanese appear. Press Enter
7. White noise appears on the screen, just wait patiently
8. One more line of text in Japanese appears. Press Enter
9. When the command prompt returns, you're done

(Translated from the README in the ZIP above)

Before step 5 I had to add the following line as line 2 of `root.sh` because my Android SDK is installed at the user level on my Linux computer, you should not need it if you install the Android SDK as admin.

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/nico/android-sdk/tools:/home/nico/android-sdk/platform-tools"
```

Be patient. The execution lasts for a few minutes, with this output (press Enter when it says `続行するにはエンターを押してください`):

```
$ sudo ./root.sh 
adb,fastbootコマンドが実行できるようインストールしてください。このスクリプトはUSBにアクセスできる権限で実行してください。
電源を入れた状態で端末をUSBデバッグを有効にしてパソコンに接続してください。
上記の手順を行った後、続行するにはエンターを押してください。

< waiting for device >
sending 'cust' (233697 KB)...
OKAY [  7.333s]
writing 'cust'...
OKAY [ 15.655s]
finished. total time: 23.002s
sending 'boot' (5298 KB)...
OKAY [  0.165s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.824s]
finished. total time: 0.989s
sending 'system' (900228 KB)...
OKAY [ 28.112s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 63.860s]
finished. total time: 91.972s
続行するにはエンターを押してください

rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.201s
$
```